# AWS Lambda project does not run because of exception

Tags: .net, aws-lambda, visual-studio-2022

I have a AWS Lambda (NET 6 ) project.
Locally it runs OK.
But when I have uploaded it to AWS it cannot start because of

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment' from assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you deploying the framework as well? Or using an already provided one?

Comment: I deploy the Lambda using VS2022 Publish Lambda menu

Comment: Can post a minimum code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Oh, it seems I have fixed. The problem was: my Lambda has a Swagger  and there was typo in Swagger path. But it was a start point for this strange non-obvious error.  As usually developer's mistake but the ASP.NET diagnostics can be better